# Completing a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Given $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ is there some way to decide when we can construct a matrix $A\in SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ s.t the first row of $A$ is $k$?

For instance when $n=2$ and $k=(a,b)$ this is just when $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can construct such a matrix if and only if the gcd of the entries
of $k$ is $1$.

The necessity is obvious, the sufficiency not quite so.
Given $k$ one can do elementary column operations over $\Bbb Z$
to reduce it to $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$. Thus there is a matrix $A$ in $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb Z)$ with $kA=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ (this is
basically the Euclidean algorithm). Then the top row
of $A^{-1}$ is $k$.

The determinant of $A^{-1}$ may be $-1$, but I'll leave you to fix that.

Comment: And this is precisely the algorithm for the Smith normal form, which generalizes to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412649

Comment: "the necessity is obvious" when you think to expand the determinant wrt the first row and see that you find the Bezout relationship... (note added for those who aren't acquainted with these issues)